# core-style correct usages and use cases

Tags: polymer, custom-element

I started using core-style in (mostly) all of my components.
 On 0.4 it was pretty helpful, but i can't really see why should i use it now with 0.5. Is there any specifics to when should i use it?

Any case in particular?

ps.: The thing is: data-binding had a bunch of problems which i haven't encountered so far on .5. Can anyone help me? I know it's a bit broad question but i don't want to go through the trouble of getting it out of my code then back in again just so i know where i should actually be using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core-style is useful to create shared themes across the application. Take a look at this artcile http://pascalprecht.github.io/2014/08/01/sharing-styles-across-web-components-with-polymer-and-core-style/

Comment: would you mind me editing your answer to contain key parts of the blog post and use the post url as a reference? i think it's more user friendly. it MAY route less visitors but it will make the answer a comprehensive and complete one. @sestva